# What is the official definition of a feature in signal classification?

Tags: classification, machine-learning

Nowadays read any paper or reference on signal classification scheme you would invariably come across the term "feature". What does feature mean exactly? What is considered a time domain feature, what is considered a frequency domain feature and what is considered a phase domain feature?

I would be glad if someone can clarify this concept for me once and for all.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_%28machine_learning%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features are properties of the signal used to describe it in some way. Sometimes the term "descriptors" is used, for example [MPEG-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-7) audio-visual description standard:

[image]

Time domain features are computed from the audio waveform, while frequency-domain or spectral features are derived after performing an FFT.

You should look through a feature-extraction software package like [Yaafe](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/features.html), to get some practical intuition. There are also many [tutorials](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS-498-DAF-PS/Lecture%208%20-%20Audio%20Features2.pdf) and [papers](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/peeters/ARTICLES/Peeters_2003_cuidadoaudiofeatures.pdf) online for further learning.